# git: mixed up branches - how to clean up

Tags: git

I worked in 2 branches and mixed up everything. Some changes intended for branch A are in branch B and the opposite. Some commits contain changes to the correct branch and the wrong wrong one at the same time. I did several commits with this mix.

Afterwards I did the changes again in the correct branches.
So I ended up with all the changes in the correct branches but on each one also the old changes that belongs to the other branch.
Then for branch A I pushed and for branch B I already made a pull request.

Question 1: How can I remove from each branch the changes that don't belong there?
I know exactly which files in a branch I need to revert to the original state.

Question 2: How can I change the already made pull request?

Comment: was that pull request already merged by the receiver?

Comment: no they didn't merged it

Comment: If they had not merged it yet, then **pull request** is of no significance. Essentially it only remembers a "note" saying "please merge my public repo branch FOOBAR into yours BARFOO". When you clean up things and then publish/push that cleanups, the pull request .. will not change. It **will still be telling the same**: "please merge my foobar into your barfoo". However, now, obviously, your foobar will be after cleanups => hence, you can consider that "pull requests" are automagically self-updating. Of course, it's handy but only as long as they are not merged yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For future reference, it would be much safer to clean this up before pushing.  At this point, you have two choices:

- You could create new branches (with new names) and migrate the desired changes to each of them.  The existing branches will end up being abandoned.
- You could "rewrite history" to fix the existing branches.  Anyone else who has fetched/pulled the existing branches will have to perform a recovery procedure (see "Recovering from upstream rebase" in the `git rebase` documentation for a general discussion of this issue).

I'll write out this procedure assuming the first option, because it's in some ways safer.  I'll give some notes on how to adjust the procedure if you want to use the history rewrite instead.  I'll show how to do `branchA`, and the procedure for `branchB` is essentially the same.  I'll assume the branch was created from `master` (so replace all references to `master` with the appropriate "parent branch" if not).

Check out the existing branch.

```
git checkout branchA
```

Assuming you don't want the new branch to be moved to the tip of `master`, you need to find the branch point.  To simplify the illustration let's create a temp tag at that point (though technically you could use SHA1 ID for this commit instead).

So you have

```
x --- A --- x <--(master)
       \
        A1 --- B1 --- AB1 --- A2 <--(branchA)
```

and you need to find `A`.  If you know that there are (in this example) 4 commits on `branchA` after it split from `master`, you could say

```
git tag rootA branchA~4
```

If you don't know the number, you can either eyeball it from a GUI front end or from `git log --graph master branchA` (if the commit history is small enough that this is practical), or if not:

```
git rev-list master..branchA
```

the last line of the output is a SHA1 for the *first commit on your branch*, so assuming that's 31337c0d3 you would

```
git tag rootA 31337c0d3^
```

(note the `^` at the end).

One way or other you should now have

```
   [rootA]
      |
x --- A --- x <--(master)
       \
        A1 --- B1 --- AB1 --- A2 <--(branchA)
```

Now create the new branch (but you can skip this step if using the "history rewrite" option).

```
git checkout -b new_branchA
```

Now begin an interactive rebasing session

```
git rebase -i --onto rootA master
```

You'll get a text editor with a "todo" list, each line representing a commit.

For commits that belong on `branchA`, leave the line unchanged (`pick` command)

For commits that belong on `branchB` - considering that you already have these changes on `branchB` - you can just change the command from `pick` to `drop`

If any commits have a mix of changes (some that belong on `branchA`, others that belong on `branchB`), change the command from `pick` to `edit`

Save and exit from the text editor, and git will start the rebase.  If you marked any commits with `edit`, then git will pause and prompt you to do your edits and then tell it to resume the rebase.

When the rebase is done you'll have

```
   [rootA]
      |
x --- A --- x <--(master)
      |\
      | A1 --- B1 --- AB1 --- A2 <--(branchA)
      \
       A1' --- Ab1' --- A2' <--(new_branchA)
```

(where `Ab1'` is the edited replacement for `AB1` in which only changes meant for `BranchA` were kept).

If you did this as a history rewrite, then `branchA` will point to `A2'` and of course there would be no `new_branchA`.

You can clean up the temp tag.

```
git tag --delete rootA
```

and unless you did a history rewrite you no longer need the old `branchA`:

```
git branch --delete branchA
```

Finally, you can push to the remote

```
git push
```

(which, in the case of a history rewrite, will need the `-f` option).

Comment: Tkx,, this is very clear. We also had more than one feature in a branche, with your solution I think it will be possible to create a new branche for each feature and starting from RootA and  just pick the changes for that feature. Then create a branche for feature 2 , starting form RootA and again pick only the changes belongs to feature2. If all features are split up delete brancheA. Is this correct?

Answer (score 0):

If you haven't pushed those branches yet, you can:

- create the branches `tmpA` and `tmpB` (for instance from `origin/A` and `origin/B`)
- [`git cherry-pick`](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-cherry-pick) the commits you need from `A` to `tmpA`, and from `B` to `tmpB`; if you need to edit the commit use the option `--no-commit`, then `git reset` to clear the index, followed by `git add -p` to only add the wanted changes and then commit the result
- reset those local branches `A` to `tmpA` (`git branch -f A tmpA`), same for `B`.
- delete `tmpA` and `tmpB`.

Comment: Tkx, with a cherry pick is a possible to divide one commit ? In one commit we have sometimes changes for brancheA and nrancheB. I thought cherry pick takes the whole commit?

Comment: @JacJac Yes, but you can use `git cherry-pick` with the `--no-commit` option. Then do a `git reset`, and you can now add only what you need with `git add -p`. Once you have added the files (or portion of a file) you need, commit, and do a `git clean -fd`.